# How can I extract shp-points values from a 3D array - (based on matching lat, lon and time)?

Tags: 3d, 2d, extract, python-xarray, shapefile

I have the problem that I have multiple data arrays (or merged together --> one big xarray dataset) and a shapefile with points. These points have inter alia columns with "geometry (=lat & lon)" and "Date". I would like to extract the values of the array/dataset at the lat, lon and time value- points the shapefile has.
My goal is to have an array (or a dataset - even better) where the extracted values of the lat, lon and time of the shapefile are stored.

Now the problem is: the shapefile is 2D and the arrays are 3D.

1. I could make a 2D array or list out of my 3D array and then try to extract with matching dates and lon and lat? [this was unfortunately not working as I could not transform my array to a list]
2. Or I try to change the shapefile to a 3D Raster and then clip the values from the existing arrays?

I would be very happy for some thoughts and help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Building off the top answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster) and assuming your points and dataset are in the same projection, you could do something like

```py
import geopandas

pts = geopandas.read_file(<your shp>)
lons = pts.geometry.x.to_list()
lats = pts.geometry.y.to_list()
values_at_pts = your_xarray_dataset.sel(lon=lons, lat=lats, method="nearest")
```